# NSURLConnection error. Works on iOS not on OSX

Tags: json, macos

I have a connection issue that I am unsure how to resolve. I have combed through the documentation for the Errors and for `NSURLConnection`. This is code that I am using in my iOS version of the same app. It works fine there, but when I brought it to the OS X version of the app, it doesn't work. This is the code:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];
NSString* data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"command=retrieve&number=%d", number];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"Starting Command");
NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",connectionError]);
    if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self parseResponseFromCommandRequest:data];
        });
    }
}];
NSLog(@"Ending Command");
```

The error occurs in the `NSURLConnection`. The output is:

> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted" UserInfo=0x610000279dc0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=url, NSErrorFailingURLKey=url}

**url** is actually a functioning url, but I replaced it here. Like I said, it works fine on iOS, but not on OS X. Is there a Library that I could be missing that is causing this? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be just a matter of setting up the entitlements to allow access. It looks from the error that it fails because it's not permitted, which would indicate the app sandbox is doing it's job. For `NSURL` you would normally use `bookmarks.app-scope` or `bookmarks.document-scope`.

See: [Enabling Security-Scoped Bookmark and URL Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW5)

Depending on how your app is using the NSURL, network entitlements may be worth looking into:

```
com.apple.security.network.server = Allow Incoming Connections
com.apple.security.network.client = Allow Outgoing Connections
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into that and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you. You were spot on. Easier than I thought. Just went to Capabilities -> Sandbox -> and checkmarked (Client). Works like a charm now.